# NullPointerException, Spring - hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate, java-ee, spring-mvc

Суть исключения ясно, немного и неудобно со столь мелким недопониманием обращаться, но факт остается фактом. Нужна ваша помощь.

> exception org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request
>   processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:973)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
>     org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>
> root cause java.lang.NullPointerException
>     ua.controller.SSController.allList(SSController.java:30)
>     sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>     sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
>     org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
>     org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:689)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:938)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
>     org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

Основные классы

servletController-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
               xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
               xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
               xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
               xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
               xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
               xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
               xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
               xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
               xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
               xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
               xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        https://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.0.xsd">
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager"/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="ua"/>
    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
        <property name="prefix" value="/webapp/jsp"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="ua.model"/>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/postschema"/>
        <property name="username" value="root"/>
        <property name="password" value="peroser12"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Контроллер

```
@Controller
public class SSController {

    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(SSController.class);

    private PostDAO postDAO;

    private CategoryDAO categoryDAO;

    @RequestMapping (value = "/index", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView allList (){
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        List<Post> posts = postDAO.getAll();
        List<Category> categories = categoryDAO.getAll();
        modelAndView.addObject("posts", posts);
        modelAndView.addObject("categories", categories);
        modelAndView.setViewName("posts");
        return modelAndView;
    }
}
```

DAOImpl

```
public abstract class AbstractDAOImplementation<G> implements AbstractDao<G> {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier(value = "sessionFactory")
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Transactional
    @Override
    public void create(G entity) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(entity);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();
    }
    @Transactional
    @Override
    public void delete(G entity) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        session.delete(entity);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();
    }
    @Transactional
    @Override
    public G edit(G entity) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        session.saveOrUpdate(entity);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();

        return entity;
    }
    @Transactional
    @Override
    public G getById(long id) {
       Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
       session.beginTransaction();
       G entity = getEntityById(session, id);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();
        return entity;
    }
    @Transactional
    @Override
    public List<G> getAll() {
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        List<G> result = getAllEntity(session);
        return result;
    }

    public abstract G getEntityById (Session session, long id);

    public abstract List<G> getAllEntity(Session session);
}
```

PostDAO

```
public class PostDAO extends AbstractDAOImplementation<Post> {
    @Override
    public Post getEntityById(Session session, long id) {
        Post result = (Post) session.createQuery("from Post where id="+id);
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Post> getAllEntity(Session session) {
        List<Post> result = session.createQuery("from Post ").list();
        return result;
    }
}
```

Post.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "post")
public class Post {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "title")
    private String title;

    @Column(name = "summary")
    private String summary;

    @Column(name = "body")
    private String body;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn
    private Category category;

    public Post() {
    }

    public Post(long id, String title, String summary, String body, Category category) {
        this.id = id;
        this.title = title;
        this.summary = summary;
        this.body = body;
        this.category = category;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getSummary() {
        return summary;
    }

    public void setSummary(String summary) {
        this.summary = summary;
    }

    public String getBody() {
        return body;
    }

    public void setBody(String body) {
        this.body = body;
    }

    public Category getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public void setCategory(Category category) {
        this.category = category;
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Post{" +
                "title='" + title + '\'' +
                ", summary='" + summary + '\'' +
                ", body='" + body + '\'' +
                ", category=" + category +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Еще есть пару классов моделей, но они ничем не отличаются особым от Post.java

Comment: Пометьте поля `postDAO` и `categoryDAO` в `SSController` аннотацией `@Autowired`, и, с большой долей вероятности, будет вам счастье.

Comment: Вы коменты в сырцах удалили, а стэктрейс еще от версии с коментами ), это если предыдущее не помогло.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DAO` аннотацией `@Repository(name="abstractImpl")`

После этого допишите в контроллере аннотации `@Autowired`, если снова будет выбивать это исключения, добавьте к `DAO` в контроллере `@Qualifier(name="abstractImpl")`.

Но кроме этого, контроллер не должен работать с `DAO` напрямую. Он должен работать с интерфейсом сервиса, который в свою очередь уже работает с `DAO`.
То есть:

```
@Service
public class AbstractServiceImpl implements AbstractService {

@Autowired
private AbstractDao dao;

@Transactional
@Override
public List<G> getAll() {
    return this.abstractDao.getAll();
}
}
```

После этого вы в контроллере пишите:

```
@Autowired
private AbstractService service;
```

Все классы и сервисы помечены своими аннотациями. А так у вас Дао это просто класс, который нигде не существует, но работает с базой если сделать его прямой инстанс.

Comment: Сейчас попробую. Есть предположение, личное, может причина в неправильно инициализированом бине Session Factory? Использовал старый способ хмл конфигурации, то ексепшн изменился на "переполнение стэка"

Comment: @ trembling11 да, личный. И новичек я. Сильно хочу уйти в IT. Вот начинаю с малого. Планирую проект прикреплять к резюме. Спасибо за совет. Ознакомлюсь

Answer (score 1):

Ваши объекты

```
private PostDAO postDAO;

private CategoryDAO categoryDAO;
```

в контроллере никак не инициализированы и равны `null`.

Если dao-классы верно помечены аннотациями (чего я не увидел в приведеном вами коде), то достаточно добавить аннотации `@Autowired` над полями `categoryDAO` и `postDAO`

Comment: dao-классы я не описывал в хмл, Сейчас проинициализировал ДАО классы, исключение осталось.
`exception
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException


java.lang.NullPointerException
 ua.dao.implementation.AbstractDAOImplementation.getAll(AbstractDAOImplementation.java:63)
 ua.controller.SSController.allList(SSController.java:30)

`

Comment: @Дмитрий, то есть спринг не знает о том, что это бины? Нужно пометить DAO классы аннотациями тоже. Если не понимаете как это работает, то вкратце и в самом простом случае так: есть аннотации `Component`, `Repository`, `Controller`, объекты классов, помеченых такими аннотациями будут созданы с помощью пустых конструкторов и помещены в контейнер спринга. Для того чтобы нужный объект из контейнера попал в поле другого класса (помеченного одной из аннотаций выше) нужно пометить поле аннотацией `@Autowired`